# UIImageView: AscpectToFit doesnt work with UIScrollView to scale it to full width

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIViewController.
This viewController contains UIScrollView with presents UIImageView. The size of my UIImage is smaller than width of parent view so I want to scale the width of this UIImageView to make it the same as parent view. Before I added UIScrollView I used .scaleAspectFit for UIImageView and it worked perfect. But now when I use UIScrollView it shows image with real size.

```
       guard let image = image, scrollView.frame.size.width > 0,  scrollView.frame.size.height > 0 else {
            return
        }
        let widthScale = scrollView.frame.size.width / image.size.width
        let heightScale = scrollView.frame.size.height / image.size.height
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = min(min(widthScale, heightScale),1)
        scrollView.zoomScale = scrollView.minimumZoomScale
        imageView.setImage(image)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)    
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
```

Comment: Why not just use AutoLayout to layout the UIImageView to the UIScrollView's edges?

Comment: cliptobounds = true might be the answer

Comment: @Fay007, didn't work for me

Comment: @mattsson sorry, didn't understand what do u mean.  I was trying to use AutoLayout to make it full width for UIImageView. Didn't help.

Comment: Specifically set the width of UIScrollView to its parent view using AutoLayout and then set the width of the UIImageView to the width of the UIScrollView, also using AutoLayout.

Comment: @mattsson yes. I added UIScrollView as full screen view. but with UIImageView it didn't help to make its width the same as UIScrollView has.

Comment: How did you add the UIScrollView as a full-screen view? Can I see the constraints?

Comment: @mattsson addSubview(subview)
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view": subview]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view": subview]))

Answer (score 0):

I changed zoomScale of UIScrollView:

```
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = min(min(widthScale, heightScale),1)
    scrollView.zoomScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
```

Instead of:

```
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = min(min(widthScale, heightScale),1)
    scrollView.zoomScale = scrollView.minimumZoomScale
```

It works.

Comment: It may work, but it's a very, very wrong way to achieve this.